# what is the timezone format of NewZealand for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code my datepicker but I don't know if this is correct or wrong. If this wrong then what is the correct code?

```
startDate: new Date().toLocaleString('en-NZ', { timeZone: 'New Zealand/Auckland' })
```

Comment: you can find full list of time zone here https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezones.json and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tolocaledatestring-method-date-javascript

Comment: in that link it is showing empty page

Comment: https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json

Comment: please mark it as answer I again posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find full list of time zone here https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json and also toLocaleDateString  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tolocaledatestring-method-date-javascript